# XFS Project Quotas on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, xfs

I'm trying to set up project quotas with XFS on a debian box and run in some problems when defining the quotas i get back an error cannot set limits: function not implemented

Am i missing something?

cat /etc/projects

```
33:/home/quotatest/a
33:/home/quotatest/b
```

cat /etc/projid

```
testproject:33
```

mountpoint of home:

```
/dev/md3 on /home type xfs (rw,pquota)
```

When i now define the quota by running

```
#xfs_quota -x home
xfs_quota> limit -p bsoft=10m bhard=20m testproject
xfs_quota: cannot set limits: Function not implemented
xfs_quota>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass to kernel options `rootflags=prjquota`.

For example, for ubuntu:

1. open `/etc/default/grub`
2. add/edit option `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rootflags=prjquota"`
3. then `sudo update-grub`
4. `sudo reboot`

For see **real** mount options do `cat /proc/mounts`, but `mount` show wrong options. I do not know it is a bug or a feature, but it is actually.

`sudo -i
echo 1:/myxfs/testdir >> /etc/projects
echo testproj:1 >> /etc/projid
xfs_quota -c 'project -s testproj'
xfs_quota -x -c 'limit -p bsoft=10m bhard=12m restproj'`